# Parse various formatted string to time

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I want to parse string to time, the string can be "hh:mm tt", or "hh:mmtt" 
"11:00am", "11:00 am", "13:00" "5:00AM" "6:00PM" , "6:00 pm", "6:00:01 pm" etc. 
I wonder how to parse it correctly.  My thought is to enumerate all the formats like below. 
But I feel it is awkward and there must be a better way.  thanks

```
        DateTime ret = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime.TryParse(timeStr, CURRENT_CULTURE_FORMATPROVIDER,Style1, out ret);
        if(ret == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            DateTime.TryParse(timeStr,CURRENT_CULTURE_FORMATPROVIDER,Style2, out ret);
        }
        if(ret == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            DateTime.TryParse(timeStr,CURRENT_CULTURE_FORMATPROVIDER,Style3, out ret);
        }
        ...
        return ret;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) seems to be working for your problem. Have a look

```
string myTime = "5:00AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime.TryParse(ss, out dt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer but not fitting to comments: reject values that are not completely clear instead of potentially guessing wrong.

While it is very tempting to guess what actual value particular string represents it is very dangerous route. The chances of guessing value wrong are higher more input "formats" you accept.

If data coming from some computer-generated source - simply rejecting unexpected data is probably best option. Consider if asking for some fixed well known culture-insensitive format works (i.e. ISO8601 optionally with timezone)

If this data coming directly from user it may be better to immediately reject the data and let user re-enter date in more precise format. If possible - simply don't let user to pick and force particular format.

If you randomly guess values incorrectly users (if they care and have to use your tool often) will learn to type values in one very particular format and have verbal instructions to only use that (like "hours two spaces colon minutes, only add PM for values in afternoon")...

Note that only some cultures (in .Net sense) have AM/PM designator, so make sure to test your code against those too.